# Rendering Problems in WPF when using Effects

Tags: .net, wpf, rendering, effect

I'm running across a problem with the rendering in WPF when I use Effects (specifically, a `DropShadowEffect`). This is what my UI is supposed to look like:
[image]

But when I start resizing the window, it will glitch at certain points and turn to this:

[image]

You can see the text is distorted and there is a darkish line on the right side of the Start Server button. The problem goes away if I remove the Effects. It this simply a bug in WPF or is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Halley said, you might "suffer" from subpixel positioning. If you compile your application against .Net 4 FrameWork, you can set the UseLayoutRounding property of your window to switch this behaviour off.

```
UseLayoutRounding=True
```

If this doesn't do the trick, try Software-Rendering to check back whether DX is giving you trouble (although I bet you won't have to go there).

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

Comment: very nice the last solution solved it,RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;

Comment: But why is the drop shadow effect causing text that would otherwise be clear to become distorted? Does the text render with transparent pixels when UseLayoutRounding is false?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your Start Server button and the search bar have center alignment, so when you resized the whole window, the control may be drawn on screen from half pixel to another half pixel. That's why the control appear blurry.

Have a try with [SnapToDevicePixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx) to see whether it helps. Set the property to true for both the controls. It should ensure all edges are drawn on physical device pixels.